# ipython notebook pylab inline - matplotlib.pyplot - how to display plot with scrollbar?

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using ipython notebook with pylab --inline

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
......
plt.figsize(14,8)
ax1=plt.subplot(311)
#data is a pandas data frame with timeseries stock data
# this plots the data
data.plot(ax=ax1)
```

This shows a plot of the stock data but its all displayed at once.
I would like to display just subrange of dates and have a scrollbar to control what range
How do I do it such that it works with the inline display of plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Inline display is a static PNG.

If you want something like that you will have to use a Javascript plotting library for now.
None that I know of will work out of the box with panda.

Answer (score 3):

You can't manipulate plots in inline-mode after they have been drawn. However, you can scale,zoom and resize plots in the interactive mode. Just start your notebook without the inline-option and all plots will be generated in an extra window with the functionality you asked for:

```
ipython notebook --pylab
```

Comment: This popped a new window and displayed the same thing that I saw inline. It does have a list of buttons at the bottom of the window, one of which seems to be zoom/pan. I seem to be able to pan the plot in all the 4 directions and the axis shifts. But I can't seem to figure out how to zoom in/out of it to seem a smaller range of either axis.

Comment: To zoom you have to choose the double-array-button and right-click on the plot. But I guess you figured that out by yourself in the meantime.

Comment: I don't think this works if the notebook is run on a distant server.